# Cloudformation script taskset cannot pull image from ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In my current setup I use cloudformation to setup an environment. All the steps configured so far seem to work, except for the taskset. I use an image on AWS ECR repo to launch a Fargate instance, which is put into a new cluster with a service.

When I create the stack all the steps succeed but the creation of the service is stuck in "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS" forever. When I look at the created service and more specifically the task, I found that cloudformation was unable to fetch the image. The error is as follows:

> STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daem)

Now when I manually try to an instance using the same image on said cluster, it works just fine. After some googling I came upon certain solutions. I have implemented all of them, such as:

- Create a network with security groups which allows outgoing traffic to all destinations
- Set the flag AssignPublicIp to 'ENABLED' in the awsvpc configuration
- Set the user execution role to the same one I used in manual creation

Note that the task does get created and it does receive a public and private IP address. Also, I have tried to throw away the ECR instance and create a new one with a new name (and of course tagged and pushed the image).

The following snippet is my service and taskset definition (renamed some sensitive info):

```
    "MyVPC": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
        "Properties": {
            "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/16",
            "Tags": [
                {"Key":"Name", "Value":"MyVPC"
                }
            ]
        },
    },
    "MyInternetGateway" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
          "Properties" : {
          }
       },
    "MySubPublic": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
        "Properties": {
            "AvailabilityZone": "eu-central-1a",
            "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/28",
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "MyVPC"
            }
        },
        "DependsOn": "MyInternetGateway"
    },
    "MySecGroup":
            {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
          "GroupDescription" : "My security group for all incoming and outgoing.",
          "GroupName" : "MySecGroup",
          "SecurityGroupEgress" : [ {
              "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0",
              "Description" : "Allow machine to reach internet.",
              "FromPort" : -1,
              "IpProtocol" : -1,
              "ToPort" : -1
            } ],
          "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
              "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0",
              "Description" : "Allow machine to be reached from the entire internet.",
              "FromPort" : -1,
              "IpProtocol" : -1,
              "ToPort" : -1
            } ],
          "VpcId" : {"Ref": "MyVPC"}
        },
        "DependsOn": "MyVPC"
    },
    "MyCluster": {
        "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster",
        "Properties": {
            "ClusterName": "MyCluster"
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "MyVPC"
        ]
    },
    "MyDockerTask": {
        "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
        "Properties": {
            "ContainerDefinitions": [
                {
                    "Cpu": 512,
                    "Image": "<NRHERE>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mysqs",
                    "Memory": 1024,
                    "MemoryReservation": 1024,
                    "Name": "MyContainer"
                }
            ],
            "Cpu": "512",
            "ExecutionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<NRHERE>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
            "Family": "MyFam",
            "Memory": "1024",
            "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
            "RequiresCompatibilities": [
                "FARGATE",
                "EC2"
            ],
            "TaskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<NRHERE>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
        },
    },
    "MyService": {
      "Type" : "AWS::ECS::Service",
      "Properties" : {
          "Cluster" : {"Fn::GetAtt": ["MyCluster", "Arn"]},
          "DesiredCount" : 1,
          "LaunchType" : "FARGATE",
          "NetworkConfiguration" : {
             "AwsvpcConfiguration" : {
                  "AssignPublicIp" : "ENABLED",
                  "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Fn::GetAtt": ["MySecGroup", "GroupId"]} ],
                  "Subnets" : [ {"Ref": "MySubPublic"}]
                }
          },
          "SchedulingStrategy" : "REPLICA",
          "ServiceName" : "MyService",
          "TaskDefinition": {"Ref": "MyDockerTask"}
        },
        "DependsOn": "MySubPublic"
    },
    "MyTaskSet": {
        "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskSet",
        "Properties": {
            "Cluster": {
                "Ref": "MyCluster"
            },
            "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
            "NetworkConfiguration" : {
                 "AwsvpcConfiguration" : {
                      "AssignPublicIp" : "ENABLED",
                      "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Fn::GetAtt": ["MySecGroup", "GroupId"]} ],
                      "Subnets" : [ {"Ref": "MySubPublic"}]
                    }
              },
            "Service": {"Ref": "MyService"},
            "TaskDefinition": {
                "Ref": "MyDockerTask"
            }
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "MyCluster"
        ]
    },
```

None of the above provided the solution. I'm open to any suggestion/solution

Comment: All is in public subnets of a default or custom VPC?

Comment: Also in the place where you found `STOPPED` message, you should be able to expand it and see full error message.

Comment: This is a custom VPC defined in the same file a little more upwards. The message I found in the Cluster -> Tasks -> <Task_id> at the bottom of the overview. I did not enable cloudwatch or anything so this was the only place to find the error. This means I cannot get any more info on it.

Comment: @Marcin: I have added in my edit the rest of the configuration of the VPC and its configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CFN template provided I can conclude that `MySubPublic` has **no  internet access**.

Specifically, I see that you are creating the following VPC-related resources:

- `AWS::EC2::VPC`
- `AWS::EC2::InternetGateway`
- `AWS::EC2::Subnet`
- `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`

However, the **problem** is the lack of:

- `AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment` which will connect the `InternetGateway` to your `VPC`
- Definitions of `AWS::EC2::RouteTable` and `AWS::EC2::Route` which will be used to make your `MySubPublic` route traffic to the `AWS::EC2::InternetGateway`.

General steps to enable internet access in a subnet are described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#vpc-igw-internet-access):

> **Attach** an internet gateway to your VPC.
>
> Add a route to your subnet's **route table** that directs internet-bound traffic to the internet gateway. If a subnet is
>   associated with a route table that has a route to an internet gateway,
>   it's known as a public subnet. If a subnet is associated with a route
>   table that does not have a route to an internet gateway, it's known as
>   a private subnet.
>
> Ensure that instances in your subnet have a globally unique IP address (**public IPv4** address, Elastic IP address, or IPv6 address).
>
> Ensure that your network **access control lists and security group** rules allow the relevant traffic to flow to and from your instance.

Comment: Ha very nice. I already found the RouteTable component missing, so I added that one. Didn't see the gatewayattachment, so I will try that. Will let you know if that worked. Thanks up front for your answer.

Comment: Finally got it. I needed much more to be configured in the end, but this problem is solved. Setting this answer as correct.

Comment: @Ludo21South Thanks and glad to help and that it worked out.